# how to display object

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular and PHP REST service
I am able to fetch data from PHP REST via calling from RestAngular.

My code looks like

```
angular
    .module("classManagement")
    .controller('ClassSectionListCtrl', function (Restangular) {
        var vm = this;
         vm.currentYr = Restangular.one("currentYear").getList().$object;
    })
```

currentYr return structure is as following

```
[{"currentYear":"2015"}]
```

How I can display output on console for return object?
I tried doing

```
console.log(vm.currentYr);
```

it return [] on console.

`console.log(vm.currentYr.currentYear);` print undefined on console.

My end target is to store currentYear for exampe 2015 in a variable.

Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Try 1 :  `console.log(vm)` , what can you see here ?  . Try 2 : keep debug pointer at `vm.currentYr` what can you see ..?

Comment: I am getting this Object {currentYr: Array[0]}
currentYr: Array[1]

Comment: I want to achieve - storing 2015 in variable.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a lot of possibilities here that you are missing.  As +vijay said, if you try to log out console.log(vm); does it show anything?  I don't know RestAngular in particular but when briefly perusing the documentation (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#collection-methods) I'm wondering if you are misusing the Restangular methods.

Comment: @TanushPal your array seems to be confusing ? vm = `{currentYr: Array[0]} currentYr: Array[1] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get you close?

```
       angular
        .module("classManagement")
        .controller('ClassSectionListCtrl', function (Restangular) {
            var vm = this;
            Restangular.all('currentYear').getList()
                .then(function(currentYears) {
                  vm.currentYr = currentYears[0].currentYear;
                  console.log(vm.currentYr);
                }
       })
```